Bx register is always equal 1 after interapt int 33h in assembly 8086
Im currently working on an assembly project and I encountered a problem, I haev a proc called 'mouse_click' that I need to call a couple of times in the project.
the first time the proc is being called it is working as it should, but the second time that its being called after the line 'int 33h' bx is always equal to one and It skips the part where I check if the mouse is clicked.
here is the code:
proc mouse_click
        
    mov ax,0h 
    int 33h       ;resets the mouse
    
    mov ax,1h 
    int 33h       ;shows the mouse
not_pressed:
    mov bx,0
    mov ax,3h 
    int 33h 
    
    cmp bx, 01h    ;checks if left mouse is pressed
    jne not_pressed 
;if left mouse is not pressed, it jumps to not_pressed and checks again if left mouse is pressed
    
    shr cx, 1   ;devide the x coordinates in 2 to get correct x coordinates
    
    mov [left_pressed_x], cx    
    ;moves the x cordinates of the mouse to left_pressed_x when left button is pressed
    
    mov [left_pressed_y], dx    
    ;moves the y cordinates of the mouse to left_pressed_y when left button is pressed      
    
    mov ax, 2h  
    int 33h
;hides the mouse because if not the coordinates of the color will be the one on the outline of the mouse so the color would never change
    
    mov bh, 0   ;sets page to zero

    mov ah, 0Dh  ; checks pixel color in mouse coordinates(left_pressed_x, left_pressed_y) 
    int 010h  
    
    ;al = color
    mov [left_pressed_color], al   
    ; moves the color to left_pressed_color 

    add [left_pressed_color], '0'
    ;turns left_pressed_color from unicode into ascii
    
    mov ax, 1 
    int 33h   ;shows the mouse agaim
    ret
endp mouse_click

I tried reseting bx before the 'int 33h' line and before the 'ret' line, but every time it gets to the 'int 33h' line bx is equal to one.

The simple probable answer is - you waited for the LMB to be pressed, did something and then you are checking again and it is STILL pressed.

How do I ‘unpress’ the LMB? Because I only press it for a brief moment and than I let go, and only after I call the proc again(when I’m not pressing the mouse)

int 33h AX=3 returns current state of buttons in BX register. It stands to reason that you get 1 there because LMB is actually pressed at the time of your second call (otherwise we go into an area of paranoia of broken drivers). Are you sure you are not doing that? How do you know LMB is depressed before the second call of mouse_click? When is it called actually?

I’m pretty sure I’m not doing that because like I said, I’m only pressing it for a brief moment, but I will try to add a piece of code to the proc mouse_click that checks if the mouse is depressed, although I really don’t think it will work..

I have added a piece of code that checks if the mouse is released, and its still not working..

How did you do that? I'd assume you used same int33h AX=3 call in a loop to wait until BX became 0, right? Assuming you did that and that loop works fine, we get to the conclusion the same exact syscall works in one place and not in the other. Which can't be unless something extremely weird is going on.

Every time You call mouse_click mouse resets because proc starts with mov ah,0 / int 33h, inside bx is number of buttons. I added some code which prints this.
Next we have loop not_pressed. So if nothig was pressed You will see 0, if RMB was pressed You will see 2. If You press LMB You will see 1 and code stops because I added wait for key service and after that rest of the code will be executed, bx = 1, procedure ends. Every time You call mouse_click this will happen.
If You decide to move mov ah,0 / int 33h outside the proc, mouse will be initialised only once. First the code will print number of buttons because this is whats inside bx later bx will contain only 1.
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
assume ds:data, cs:code
segment data
    left_pressed_x      dw ?
    left_pressed_y      dw ?
    left_pressed_color  db ?
    pos_x               dw ?
    pos_y               dw ?
    
    status_text         db "Number of buttons:  ",13,10
                        db "  Pressed:$"
ends

segment code
Start:
proc main
    mov ax, data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ax,13h              ; mode 13h, 320x200x256
    int 10h 

    mov ax,0a000h           ; es = video mem address
    mov es,ax

;-----------------------    

    mov ah,02h              ; move cursor
    mov dh,0
    mov dl,2
    int 10h
    
    mov ah,09h              ; show status text
    lea dx, status_text
    int 21h

;   mov ax,0h 
    ;int 33h                ; resets the mouse

    main_loop:
        call mouse_click

        mov ah,01h          ; check keyboard buffer
        int 16h
    
        jz no_keys
        
        mov ah,00h
        int 16h
        
        cmp al,27           ; if ESC pressed, exit app
        je quit
        
        no_keys:
    jmp main_loop

    quit:
        MOV AX, 3h
        int 10h 

        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h

endp main

proc mouse_click
    mov ax,0h 
    int 33h                 ; resets the mouse
                            ; bx = number of buttons
    mov ah,02h              ; position
    mov dh,0
    mov dl,21
    int 10h
 
    mov ah,02h              ; print number of buttons   
    mov dl,bl
    add dl,30h
    int 21h         

    mov ax,1h 
    int 33h                  ;shows the mouse  
    
    not_pressed:
        ;mov bx,0
        mov ax,3h           ; mouse status
        int 33h             ; bx = button number
 
        mov ah,02h          ; position of button number
        mov dh,1
        mov dl,13
        int 10h
 
        mov ah,02h          ; inside loop: 0 - nothing was pressed
        mov dl,bl           ;              2 - RMB
        add dl,30h          ;              3 - LMB + RMB
        int 21h             ;              4 - CMB
    
        cmp bx, 01h         ; we go outside if bx = 1, checks if left mouse is pressed
        jne not_pressed 
;if left mouse is not pressed, it jumps to not_pressed and checks again if left mouse is pressed

        
        mov ah,02h              ; position 
        mov dh,1
        mov dl,13
        int 10h
 
        mov ah,02h              ; print 1 and stop (wait for key press)
        mov dl,bl               ; just to see that LMB was pressed
        add dl,30h              ; after that bx is changed on enter to mouse_click
        int 21h                 ; bx = number of mouse buttons
    
        mov ah,08h
        int 21h
    
    shr cx, 1   ;devide the x coordinates in 2 to get correct x coordinates
    
    mov [left_pressed_x], cx    
    ;moves the x cordinates of the mouse to left_pressed_x when left button is pressed
    
    mov [left_pressed_y], dx    
    ;moves the y cordinates of the mouse to left_pressed_y when left button is pressed      
    
    mov ax, 2h  
    int 33h
;hides the mouse because if not the coordinates of the color will be the one on the outline of the mouse so the color would never change
    
    mov bh, 0   ;sets page to zero

    mov ah, 0Dh  ; checks pixel color in mouse coordinates(left_pressed_x, left_pressed_y) 
    int 010h  
    
    ;al = color
    mov [left_pressed_color], al   
    ; moves the color to left_pressed_color 

    add [left_pressed_color], '0'
    ;turns left_pressed_color from unicode into ascii
    
    mov ax, 1 
    int 33h   ;shows the mouse agaim
    ret
endp mouse_click
ends ;code

end Start

